# Getting 'unknown error: net::ERR_CONNECTION_CLOSED' Error running webdriver in Docker Linux

Tags: python-3.x, asynchronous, python-asyncio, rhel7, chrome-web-driver

I am trying to web scrape my companies website. To speed up, I have used Asynchronous Web Scraping library Arsenic.
When I run this Code I see mutliple drivers are spawned at different local ports.

```
Starting ChromeDriver 109.0.5414.74 (e7c5703604daa9cc128ccf5a5d3e993513758913-refs/branch-heads/5414@{#1172}) on port 59479
Only local connections are allowed.
Please see https://chromedriver.chromium.org/security-considerations for suggestions on keeping ChromeDriver safe.
[1674821791.415][SEVERE]: bind() failed: Cannot assign requested address (99)
ChromeDriver was started successfully.
Starting ChromeDriver 109.0.5414.74 (e7c5703604daa9cc128ccf5a5d3e993513758913-refs/branch-heads/5414@{#1172}) on port 40633
Only local connections are allowed.
Please see https://chromedriver.chromium.org/security-considerations for suggestions on keeping ChromeDriver safe.
[1674821791.853][SEVERE]: bind() failed: Cannot assign requested address (99)
ChromeDriver was started successfully.
Starting ChromeDriver 109.0.5414.74 (e7c5703604daa9cc128ccf5a5d3e993513758913-refs/branch-heads/5414@{#1172}) on port 47115
Only local connections are allowed.
Please see https://chromedriver.chromium.org/security-considerations for suggestions on keeping ChromeDriver safe.
[1674821791.952][SEVERE]: bind() failed: Cannot assign requested address (99)
ChromeDriver was started successfully.
Starting ChromeDriver 109.0.5414.74 (e7c5703604daa9cc128ccf5a5d3e993513758913-refs/branch-heads/5414@{#1172}) on port 58835
Only local connections are allowed.
Please see https://chromedriver.chromium.org/security-considerations for suggestions on keeping ChromeDriver safe.
[1674821792.358][SEVERE]: bind() failed: Cannot assign requested address (99)
ChromeDriver was started successfully.
```

---

**Note:** The bind() failed error is a non-issue here as the chromeDriver started succesfully despite this error.

It works but after scraping some urls it is giving an Error, which I am not able to understand.

```
2023-01-27 12:16.44 [error    ] 
error data={'error': 'unknown error', 'message': 'unknown error: net::ERR_CONNECTION_CLOSED\n  (Session info: headless chrome=109.0.5414.119)', 'stacktrace': '#0 0x55e6edd7e303 <unknown>\n#1 0x55e6edb52d37 <unknown>\n#2 0x55e6edb4ad85 <unknown>\n#3 0x55e6edb3df87 <unknown>\n#4 0x55e6edb3f4e9 <unknown>\n#5 0x55e6edb3e2fe <unknown>\n#6 0x55e6edb3d432 <unknown>\n#7 0x55e6edb3d285 <unknown>\n#8 0x55e6edb3bc77 <unknown>\n#9 0x55e6edb3c2a4 <unknown>\n#10 0x55e6edb54c48 <unknown>\n#11 0x55e6edbc7f15 <unknown>\n#12 0x55e6edbaf982 <unknown>\n#13 0x55e6edbc788c <unknown>\n#14 0x55e6edbaf753 <unknown>\n#15 0x55e6edb82a14 <unknown>\n#16 0x55e6edb83b7e <unknown>\n#17 0x55e6eddcd32e <unknown>\n#18 0x55e6eddd0c0e <unknown>\n#19 0x55e6eddb3610 <unknown>\n#20 0x55e6eddd1c23 <unknown>\n#21 0x55e6edda5545 <unknown>\n#22 0x55e6eddf26a8 <unknown>\n#23 0x55e6eddf2836 <unknown>\n#24 0x55e6ede0dd13 <unknown>\n#25 0x7fae53b0fea5 start_thread\n'} message=unknown error: net::ERR_CONNECTION_CLOSED
  (Session info: headless chrome=109.0.5414.119) stacktrace=#0 0x55e6edd7e303 <unknown>
#1 0x55e6edb52d37 <unknown>
#2 0x55e6edb4ad85 <unknown>
#3 0x55e6edb3df87 <unknown>
#4 0x55e6edb3f4e9 <unknown>
#5 0x55e6edb3e2fe <unknown>
#6 0x55e6edb3d432 <unknown>
#7 0x55e6edb3d285 <unknown>
#8 0x55e6edb3bc77 <unknown>
#9 0x55e6edb3c2a4 <unknown>
#10 0x55e6edb54c48 <unknown>
#11 0x55e6edbc7f15 <unknown>
#12 0x55e6edbaf982 <unknown>
#13 0x55e6edbc788c <unknown>
#14 0x55e6edbaf753 <unknown>
#15 0x55e6edb82a14 <unknown>
#16 0x55e6edb83b7e <unknown>
#17 0x55e6eddcd32e <unknown>
#18 0x55e6eddd0c0e <unknown>
#19 0x55e6eddb3610 <unknown>
#20 0x55e6eddd1c23 <unknown>
#21 0x55e6edda5545 <unknown>
#22 0x55e6eddf26a8 <unknown>
#23 0x55e6eddf2836 <unknown>
#24 0x55e6ede0dd13 <unknown>
#25 0x7fae53b0fea5 start_thread
 status=500 type=<class 'arsenic.errors.UnknownError'>
failed getting session
```

I am running this in Docker using Linux RHEL 7 image.
Python 3.8
Arsenic 21.8
Chrome v109
ChromeDriver v109

Here Is the Code.

```py
import asyncio
from arsenic import get_session, stop_session, browsers, services

def initialize_webdriver():
    service = services.Chromedriver(binary=os.environ.get('CHROMEDRIVER_PATH'))
    browser = browsers.Chrome()
    browser.capabilities = {
        "goog:chromeOptions": {"args": ["--no-sandbox", "--headless", "--verbose",
                                        "--disable-gpu", "--disable-web-security", "--allow_insecure_localhost",
                                        "--disable-dev-shm-usage", "--enable-javascript",
                                        f"--proxy-server={os.environ.get('http_proxy')}"
                                        ]
                          }
    }
    return service, browser


async def scraper(limit, service, browser, url):
    async with limit:
        try:
            async with get_session(service, browser) as session:
                # print("inside scraper")
                await session.get(url)
                try:
                   <code to get web elements>
                  return results
               except asyncio.TimeoutError as msg:
                    print("failed scraping url ", url)
                    await stop_session(session)
                    print(msg)
                    return []
        except (arsenic.errors.UnknownArsenicError, arsenic.errors.UnknownError, arsenic.errors.ArsenicError)as msg:
            print("failed getting session")
            global failed_urls
            failed_urls.append(urls)
            limit.release()

            return []

async def run(service, browser, urls):
    limit = asyncio.Semaphore(30)
    results = await asyncio.gather(*[scraper(limit, service, browser,
                                                 url) for url in urls)])
    print(results)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    failed_urls = []
    urls = extract_urls() # it collects urls from website's sitemap url
    service, browser = initialize_webdriver()
    asyncio.run(run(service, browser, urls))
```

After reducing the semaphore to 20, I am getting the same issue.
Need to understand why this error is occurring and how to resolve this.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into a problem of a slightly different nature *"ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED"*, but under similar conditions (Docker).

I wrote the  field with value "80" in my nginx setting in docker-compose.yaml(you can see it on the picture).

And I also added "127.0.0.1:8000" to my uwsgi **file.ini** because i was sending some requests to this IP.
May be you should try to look for solution in docker/uwsgi or in their relationship between each other.

[image: "screenshot"]